# kraken2 to OTU table creation

Tags: genome, microbial-genomics

I did run kraken2 and I get two kinds of output
How do I generate OTU table from these outputs for phyloseq usage?

Comment: Hi @twinkle if you don't get a response, maybe expand your question to provide details of your outputs? There are kraken users on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run [Bracken](https://github.com/jenniferlu717/Bracken) to the Kraken2 report output to estimate abundance.

Comment: I have multiple text file as output, and text file contains data like 2 column format with thousands of rows. from these type of outputs how do I generate OTU table

Comment: you will use the `--report` option output from Kraken2 like the input of Bracken for an abundance quantification of your samples. E.g. `kraken2 --db ${KRAKEN_DB} --report ${SAMPLE}.kreport ${SAMPLE}.fq > ${SAMPLE}.kraken` where **`${SAMPLE}.kreport`** will be your input for Bracken.